# remove devices and software raid1

Tags: linux, centos, software-raid

Hello i have problem with my server where i trying to remove devices and raid
i removed /dev/sda1 with:

```
mdadm --manage /dev/md3 --fail /dev/sda1
mdadm --manage /dev/md3 --remove /dev/sda1
```

but when i try the same with sdb1 i got

```
hot remove failed for /dev/sdb1: Device or resource busy
```

i found all answers here what i already used for sda1

```
lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    1 447.1G  0 disk
└─sda1        8:1    1 447.1G  0 part
sdb           8:16   1 447.1G  0 disk
└─sdb1        8:17   1 447.1G  0 part
  └─md3       9:3    0   447G  0 raid1
loop0         7:0    0     4G  0 loop  /home/virtfs/user/var/tmp
nvme0n1     259:0    0   477G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0    32G  0 part
│ └─md0       9:0    0    32G  0 raid1 [SWAP]
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0   512M  0 part
│ └─md1       9:1    0 511.4M  0 raid1 /boot
└─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0 444.4G  0 part
  └─md2       9:2    0 444.3G  0 raid1 /
nvme1n1     259:4    0   477G  0 disk
├─nvme1n1p1 259:5    0    32G  0 part
│ └─md0       9:0    0    32G  0 raid1 [SWAP]
├─nvme1n1p2 259:6    0   512M  0 part
│ └─md1       9:1    0 511.4M  0 raid1 /boot
└─nvme1n1p3 259:7    0 444.4G  0 part
  └─md2       9:2    0 444.3G  0 raid1 /
```

more info about:

```
 mdadm --detail /dev/md3
/dev/md3:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Mon Mar 11 00:19:21 2019
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 468718400 (447.00 GiB 479.97 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 468718400 (447.00 GiB 479.97 GB)
      Raid Devices : 2
     Total Devices : 1
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Wed Oct  9 18:49:28 2019
             State : clean, degraded
    Active Devices : 1
   Working Devices : 1
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : bitmap

              Name : host.name.tld:3  (local to host host.name.tld)
              UUID : 02aec08a:fb79e60e:c21a3562:d747c22f
            Events : 2413

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       -       0        0        0      removed
       1       8       17        1      active sync   /dev/sdb1
```

i tried to find what using it with lsof | grep /mnt/home2/ because i used that raid as home2

without luck

info about system: CentOS 7, cPanel server shared hosting, production server, CloudLinux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

removed from fdisk and mdadm conf fail after reboot it was possible to remove mdadm --manage /dev/md3 --remove and that is it

Comment: did you mean to say that you removed (something) from a conf ... **file**?

Comment: yes /dev/md3 removed from conf files

Comment: Then you may want to [edit your post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/547907/edit) to fix the typo. There's also code formatting that you can use to distinguish commands from prose -- backticks, indented with four spaces on its own line, or triple-backticks (code fences).